# JDK version in react-native doctor

Tags: java, android, react-native, java-8

Today Java woke up to make my life a living hell... I wasn't able to run react-native run android and when I went to check the react-native doctor to see if anything was happening.

Turns out that there's something wrong with the JDK Version of Java, be I've installed the right version and it seems it didn't worked.

Any tips?

[image: the error on terminal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I had the exact same situation, and what solved my problem was removing conflicting paths I had in my environment.

I've got that exact same message from ***react-native doctor***, but it seems unrelated. I'm still getting it, but the problem was solved by removing the bad paths.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll take a look... no luck yet... ;/

Comment: Which path? What is the path did you remove?

Comment: For me I had paths to java JRE executables in system environment variable `Path`, usually to `Program Files\Common Files\Oracle`, removing them helped, was just solving probably the same issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408768/react-native-failed-to-find-jdk-and-android-sdk-react-native/73206678#73206678