# React-Native Failed to find JDK and android SDK react native

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I am building a react native app, I made all configurations and they are supposed to be. But  unfortunately my build has failed. When I run react-native doctor still JDK is recognized and my Android SDK versions are all found to be not supported including the recommended on. I am stuck I do not know what to do. I am running these on windows. Could any please help me out? thanks in advance. These screenshots show what I am talking about[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWHSQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EB57.png)

Answer (score -1):

I was having similar issues. The SDK version required is usually an easier one to fix, although I am a bit suspicious about the 'b' letter in the version, my list of available SDKs has no such version - maybe upgrading/downgrading react native will help.

[image: my list of available SDKs has no such version]

SDK manager in the Android Studio will let you install desired Android SDK version if you enable the option 'show package details', it is usually a checkbox in the right bottom corner of the SDK manager.

JDK dependency is usually some tricky value in Environment variables. In my case, JDK was not being found by `doctor`  although I had JDK `1.8.2` properly installed. I let doctor fix the dependency in the end, it installed JDK 11 into `AppData` and the next inspection *failed as well*. I still suspect the react native to not to support all `1.8.x` JDK versions, since the below helped. Maybe it would've helped even without installing JDK 11, haven't tried.

The problem was that there are inputs in both user and system variables that get mixed in. I had to go through `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` variables for both user and the system to change the JDK path to use JDK 11. Some values were correctly set by `doctor`, still some were evidently not. What helped for me in the end was to remove all paths

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;

from the system environment variable `Path` (**not** the user). These contained paths to JRE executables, the 1.8.x version. After that, JDK was suddenly getting recognized.